# How to rename goals in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

In the Maven document [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins), a goal of `display:time` is described that outputs the current time. The plugin is as follows:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-touch-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>timestamp</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

I have several questions relating to this plugin:

1. How can I change the name of the goal to, for example, `foo:bar`? (Why does neither `display` nor `time` appear anywhere in the XML fragment? How can you tell, from looking at the fragment, what goals it defines?)
2. How can I manually run this goal? (For similar constructs, the equivalent of `mvn display:time` sometimes works, but this doesn't work consistently.)
3. How can I see if this goal exists? (i.e. list available goals; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709625/maven-command-to-list-lifecycle-phases-along-with-bound-goals) suggests this is impossible.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can I change the name of the goal to, for example, `foo:bar`? (Why does neither `display` nor `time` appear anywhere in the XML fragment? How can you tell, from looking at the fragment, what goals it defines?)

To be precise, in `foo:bar`, `foo` is the "plugin goal prefix" and `bar` is the "goal". And while the later is derived from naming conventions (or can be [configured](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugin-prefix.html#ex-plugin-prefix)<sup>1</sup>), the former comes from an annotation of the `BarMojo`, the class that implements the plugin logic. Something like this:

```
/**
 * Do the wonderful bar.
 * @goal bar
 * @requiresProject false
 */
public class BarMojo extends AbstractMojo
{
    ...
}
```

Changing the goal requires modifying the annotation of the mojo of a plugin and rebuilding it.

Regarding the documentation you linked to, there is a clearly mismatch between the goal `time` and the XML fragment which binds a `timestamp` goal to the `process-test-resources` phase. This must be a typo.

> How can I manually run this goal? (For similar constructs, the equivalent of mvn display:time sometimes works, but this doesn't work consistently.)

You can call it like this:

```
mvn com.mycompany.example:maven-touch-plugin:1.0:timestamp
```

You could make this command shorter by adding `com.mycompany.example` to the [Plugin Groups](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugin-prefix.html#ex-plugin-groups) in your `settings.xml` (`org.apache.maven.plugins` and `org.codehaus.mojo` are declared by default in case you wonder how it works for those plugins)

```
<settings>
  ...
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>com.mycompany.example</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

Then, because the plugin name matches the `${prefix}-maven-plugin` or `maven-${prefix}-plugin` patterns, you could execute:

```
mvn touch:timestamp
```

Following the convention is recommended but, as I said, the prefix can also be [configured](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugin-prefix.html#ex-plugin-prefix).

> How can I see if this goal exists?

Check the plugin documentation (derived from the plugin sources) or the plugin sources.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Note that there is also a typo at the bottom of the mentioned page of the Maven Book. The way to execute the plugin with a custom prefix should be **`mvn blah:echo`** (see [MVNREF-145](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNREF-145)).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a chance that the documentation may have a typo. Plugin goals are specified by `plugin-name:goal-name`. That XML would bind the goal `touch:timestamp` to the `process-test-resources` phase. That fragment doesn't have anything to do with `display:time`.

1. As far as I know, it is impossible to rename maven goals. (It seems like it would just make things more confusing.) The plugin source code is what defines goals, not the pom. The <executions> tag in the pom merely allows you to bind plugin goals to phases, or rebind goals if they already have a default phase.
2. You should be able to run a goal with `prefix:goalName`. Most often, the prefix is simply whatever is between "maven-" and "-plugin" in the artifactId. e.g. `touch:timestamp`. This is complicated in a few situations since plugin authors can specify a "goalPrefix" different from the plugin name, but I haven't ever run into problems with this.
3. The best way to find out what goals a plugin defines, and what phases they are bound to by default is to read the plugin documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To your first one. The name of the goal is defined by the plugin (there is an annotation for that). If have the source code you change that.
Taking a look at the XML you can't know what kind of goals a plugin defines only the ones which are given in the XML. The best location is to look at the documentation of the plugin.
Second one: You have to check the docs. Usually pluginname:goal ...May be you have to specify the full path of the plugin (groupId).
To the third: Usually should be able to use the help plugin take a look at the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 1):

*How can I change the name of the goal to, for example, foo:bar? (Why does neither display nor time appear anywhere in the XML fragment? How can you tell, from looking at the fragment, what goals it defines?)*

To change the name of the prefix to "foo" you need to configure the maven plugin "plugin".

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <goalPrefix>foo</goalPrefix>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

To change the name of the goal, you need to edit the javadoc within the plugin java source

```
/**
 * Prints a timestamp to console
 *
 * @goal bar
 */
public class TimestampMojo extends AbstractMojo {
  // ...
}
```

Add the plugin prefix to your settings.xml file

```
<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>com.mycompany.example</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

*How can I manually run this goal?*

```
mvn com.mycompany.example:foo:bar
```

or with plugin prefix setting (above)

```
mvn foo:bar
```

*How can I see if this goal exists? (i.e. list available goals)*

Add the following to the maven plugin plugin element and you can use foo:help to print out the list of goals.

```
<plugin>
...
<executions>
<execution>
<id>generated-helpmojo</id>
<goals>
<goal>helpmojo</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```