# Finding out about all build steps a Maven build will do with a project

Tags: maven

I am working with a rather complex open source Java project that uses Maven as its build tool.
It is a multi-module project with a parent POM, several submodules, WAR overlays, goals bound to nondefault phases and whatnot.

The build complexity is therefore high, and [`mvn help:describe -Dcmd=package`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2066145/923560) is not informative enough to give an outline about what gets done during a build.

Is there a way to get an overview about all build steps?

Comment: Hm...maybe i misunderstand a thing...but does `mvn  clean package | tee mvn.log` does not fit your needs? What would you exactly like to know about that particular build?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think that there's a Maven plugin that will do what you are asking out of the box. The way most of us Maven users do is to start from the root POM and simply run `mvn clean install`. What this gives you is *more or less** all the plugin executions that are part of the default build.

Please note that there could also be *profiles* that may change things. Running `mvn help:all-profiles` will list all the available profiles and tell you where they come from (`settings.xml`, root POM, child POM, etc). This, together with perhaps `mvn help:active-profiles`, will help you get an idea of what is going on.

Also bear in mind that profiles are **not** mutually exclusive, so even though this allows for flexibility, they can sometimes cancel each other out or produce strange results for unexpected combinations.

I am sorry that I can't give you better advice than this. I don't know your level of Maven expertise so this information might be irrelevant to you.