# maven print phase of the lifecycle during build

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

How to print which phase running while maven builds the project ? Let us say I run mvn install , then what I see is :

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ site-order-parent ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.3/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.3-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/xxx/Cdk/site-order/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) > generate-sources @ site-order-parent >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ site-order-parent ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.3/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.3-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/xxx/Cdk/site-order/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) < generate-sources @ site-order-parent <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar (attach-sources) @ site-order-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:report (default-report) @ site-order-parent ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ site-order-parent ---
```

We see the format `<plugin_name> : version : goal (execution Id) @ artifact name` , but I need to see which phase of the lifecycle was active when this is happening ?

Comment: use ``-X`` (debug) flag of mvn, you will get A LOT more infos.

Comment: @spi , I did but did not find any phase info. I searched the logs for `phase` keyword but found nothing. Are you sure we get phase info in `-X` ?

Comment: right, did confound some default execution ids with phases. Anyway, here there is some valuable infos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709625/maven-command-to-list-lifecycle-phases-along-with-bound-goals

Comment: Why do you need that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise , when I see the build happening , I want to see it in organized way like now the compile phase has begun and this many goals ran in it , now test phase has begun and this many goals ran in it. This helps me to better grasp where a build is present during its process. Right now , just seeing plugin and goals in logs , i have to reverse engineer what phase it might be in.

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no such things to print out the life cycle phases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an complete answer in the comments. So, I am combining them and posting on their behalf.

As @khmarbaise commented , currently this is not possible in maven 3.

But there is something that can be helpful -  [buildplan-maven-plugin](http://buildplan.jcgay.fr/list-phase-mojo.html) as commented by @spi.

[How will this plugin be useful in our scenario ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35610377/2844702)